# Laravel application bootstrap setting options

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a Laravel app using a third party library for various helper function.

The way this library acts depends on the environment (dev, test, prod).

I want to set the library's debug setting based on the value of the Laravel `.env` setting, and I assumed that the best place to set this would be in the `bootstrap/app.php` file. So I was trying something like this right before `$app` is returned:

```
MyCustomLibrary::set_debug(config('app.debug'));
return $app;
```

This throws the error `ReflectionException: Class config does not exist`.

Where would I set this if not in the `bootstrap/app.php`? Is there a different syntax I'd use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think inside the AppServiceProvider on the boot method would be a nice place.

```
use MyCustomLibrary;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    public function boot()
    {
        MyCustomLibrary::set_debug(config('app.debug'));
    }
    ...
```